# Is it possible in cloudfront analytics to see Top referrers for specific objects?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

In AWS **cloudfront Reports&Analytics** there is option to see **top 25 referrers** from which your CDN was requested from."Request count" seems to be summed requests for all objects that are on selected CDN, example: requests for /script1.js and /script2.js are summed together if they are on same cdn.

**Is it possible to see top referrer only for specific object**? In this case I would like to see top 25 referrers for /script1.js.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the **reports and analytics** tool in cloudfront console you get very basic and high-level information. To do analysis like you asked, you can use Athena. You can query your Cloudfront logs with SQL query. Of course, you have to have Cloudfront log delivery and Atehna setup in first plce.

Comment: ok tnx. A bit disappointing that they dont provide a bit more detailed reporting directly in 2023...

Comment: Indeed. I suppose once you have expected data from Athena, you can create a dashboard by using Quicksight.